# Creating XPATH rows to dynamic tables using pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I am new to pyspark (version 1.6 ) and I i have serious of XPATHS ( in a processed key value ) ane its values in a list file

```
root/catalog~1/product~1/arrived-on~1='today'
root/catalog~1/product~1/arrived-for~1='gha'
root/catalog~1/product~1/catalog-item~1/price~1='39.95'
root/catalog~1/product~1/catalog-item~1/name~1='A'
root/catalog~1/product~1/catalog-item~2/name~1='C'
root/catalog~1/product~1/catalog-item~2/price~1='49.95'
root/catalog~1/product~1/catalog-item~3/name~1='B'
root/catalog~1/product~1/catalog-item~3/price~1='100'
root/catalog~1/product~2/arrived-on~1'yesterday'
root/catalog~1/product~2/arrived-for~1='gha'
root/catalog~1/product~2/catalog-item~1/price~1='399.95'
root/catalog~1/product~2/catalog-item~1/name~1='AA'
root/catalog~1/product~2/catalog-item~2/name~1='CC'
root/catalog~1/product~2/catalog-item~2/price~1='939.95'
root/catalog~1/product~2/catalog-item~3/name~1='AB'
root/catalog~1/product~2/catalog-item~3/price~1='239'
root/catalog~2/product~1/arrived-on~1='Monday'
root/catalog~2/product~1/arrived-for~1='raf'
root/catalog~2/product~1/catalog-item~1/price~1='70'
root/catalog~2/product~1/catalog-item~1/name~1='AAA'
root/catalog~2/product~1/catalog-item~2/name~1='CCCC'
root/catalog~2/product~1/catalog-item~2/price~1='49.95'
root/catalog~2/product~1/catalog-item~2/anytag~1='anytag'
root/catalog~2/product~1/catalog-item~3/name~1='B'
root/catalog~2/product~1/catalog-item~3/price~1='D'
root/catalog~2/product~2/arrived-on~1'today'
root/catalog~2/product~2/arrived-for~1='jaf'
root/catalog~2/product~2/catalog-item~1/price~1='39.95'
root/catalog~2/product~2/catalog-item~1/name~1='A'
root/catalog~2/product~2/catalog-item~2/name~1='C'
root/catalog~2/product~2/catalog-item~2/price~1='39.95'
root/catalog~2/product~2/catalog-item~2/extratag~1='only on this'
```

I am expecting transform this output into number of tables  the value before = is columnname and the one before that is table-name.

In this case i will end up having 2 tables. 
Tbl 1 Catalog table

```
catalog product arrived-on  arrived-for
1   1   today   gha
1   2   yesterday   gha
2   1   Monday  raf
2   2   today   raf
```

table 2 - catalog-item table

```
catalog product catalog-item    name    price   extratag    Anytag
1   1   1   A   39.95   NULL    NULL
1   1   2   C   49.95   NULL    NULL
1   1   3   B   100 NULL    NULL
1   2   1   AA  399.95  NULL    NULL
1   2   2   CC  939.95  NULL    NULL
1   2   3   AB  239 NULL    NULL
2   1   1   AAA 70  NULL    NULL
2   1   2   CCC 49.95   NULL    anytag
2   1   3   B   D   NULL    NULL
2   2   2   C   39.95   NULL    NULL
2   2   2   A   39.95   Only on This    NULL
```

So far what i have done is split the xpath value into multiple columns

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f    
myrdd=sc.textfile("<fileanme>").map(lambda line: line.split("=")
df=myrdd.toDF(['xpath'],['value'])
df=df.withcolumn('columnname',f.reverse(f.split(f.reverse(df.xpath),"/")[0]))
df=df.withcolumn('tablename',f.reverse(f.split(f.reverse(df.xpath),"/")[1]))
df=df.withcolumn('hirearchy_1',f.split(f.col('xpath'),"/")[1])
df=df.withcolumn('hirearchy_3',f.split(f.col('xpath'),"/")[3])
df=df.withcolumn('hirearchy_2',f.split(f.col('xpath'),"/")[2])
df=df.withcolumn('hirearchy_4',f.split(f.col('xpath'),"/")[4])
df=df.withcolumn('layer_2',f.split(f.col('hirearchy_2'),"/")[1])
df=df.withcolumn('layer_3',f.split(f.col('hirearchy_3'),"/")[1])
df=df.withcolumn('layer_4',f.split(f.col('hirearchy_4'),"/")[1])
df=df.withcolumn('hirearchy_1',f.split(f.col('hirearchy_1'),"~")[0])
df=df.withcolumn('hirearchy_3',f.split(f.col('xpath'),"~")[0])
df=df.withcolumn('hirearchy_2',f.split(f.col('xpath'),"~")[0])
df=df.withcolumn('hirearchy_4',f.split(f.col('xpath'),"~")[0])
```

I wanted to split further dynamically to make everything / and ~ as delimeter and make it as columns.

I want to pick columname tablename hirechary and tranform with the layer value and bring it to the required out. I have only listed the first huirechary over here . I am looking for something generic whihc will dynamically add columns and do the transpose and bring me the required columns.

Any suggestions pointers and answers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In RDD we can do more cleansing, and DF for more performance.

```
myrdd=sc.textFile("data/xpath.txt").map(lambda x: x.replace('1=',''))

def arr(x): 
    return 'catalog-item' not in x 

def cat(x): 
    return 'catalog-item' in x
# Maybe someone can write better definitions on following 
def makeUpArr(x,head):
    line = ''
    for i in head: 
        found = ''
        for k in x:
            if k[0] == i:
                found = k[1]
        line += found  + ','
    return line[:-1]

def lastCol(y):
    line = ''
    for i in range(len(y)):
        if i%2 == 0:
            line += '(' + y[i] + ',' 
        else:
            line +=  y[i] + '),' 
    return line[:-1]


rdd_arr, rdd_cat = (myrdd.filter(f) for f in (arr , cat))
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, col, lit

#---------
rdd_arrHead = rdd_arr.map(lambda x : [i.split('~')[0] for i in x.split('/') if (i != 'root')]).flatMap(lambda x : x)
header_arr = [i for i in rdd_arrHead.distinct().collect()]

rdd_arrData = rdd_arr.map(lambda x : [(i.split('~')[0] ,i.split('~')[1] ) for i in x.split('/') if ( i != 'root')]).map(lambda x : makeUpArr(x,header_arr)).map(lambda x : x.split(','))
dfArr = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd_arrData, header_arr)
#---------
rdd_catHead = rdd_cat.map(lambda x : [i.split('~')[0] for i in x.split('/') if (i != 'root')]).flatMap(lambda x : x)
header_cat = [i for i in rdd_catHead.distinct().collect()]

rdd_catData = rdd_cat.map(lambda x : [(i.split('~')[0] ,i.split('~')[1] ) for i in x.split('/') if ( i != 'root')]).map(lambda x : makeUpArr(x,header_cat)).map(lambda x : x.split(','))
dfData = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd_catData, header_cat)

#dfArr.groupBy(['catalog', 'product']).agg(F.max(col('arrived-on')).alias('arrived-on'), F.max(col('arrived-for')).alias('arrived-for')).show()
>>> dfArr.groupBy(['catalog', 'product']).agg(*[F.max(dfArr[i]) for i in header_arr if i != 'catalog' and i != 'product'  ]).show()
+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+
|catalog|product| arrived-on|arrived-for|
+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+
|      1|      1|    'today'|      'gha'|
|      2|      2|    'today'|      'jaf'|
|      1|      2|'yesterday'|      'gha'|
|      2|      1|   'Monday'|      'raf'|
+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+

#dfData.groupBy(['catalog', 'product','catalog-item']).agg(F.max(col('name')).alias('name'),F.max(col('price')).alias('price'),F.max(col('extratag')).alias('extratag'), F.max(col('Anytag')).alias('Anytag')).show()
>>> dfData.groupBy(['catalog', 'product','catalog-item']).agg(*[F.max(dfData[i]) for i in header_cat if i != 'catalog' and i != 'product' and i != 'catalog-item'  ]).show()

+-------+-------+------------+------+--------+--------------+--------+
|catalog|product|catalog-item|  name|   price|      extratag|  Anytag|
+-------+-------+------------+------+--------+--------------+--------+
|      1|      1|           3|   'B'|   '100'|              |        |
|      2|      2|           1|   'A'| '39.95'|              |        |
|      1|      1|           1|   'A'| '39.95'|              |        |
|      2|      1|           3|   'B'|     'D'|              |        |
|      1|      2|           1|  'AA'|'399.95'|              |        |
|      1|      2|           2|  'CC'|'939.95'|              |        |
|      2|      1|           2|'CCCC'| '49.95'|              |'anytag'|
|      1|      1|           2|   'C'| '49.95'|              |        |
|      1|      2|           3|  'AB'|   '239'|              |        |
|      2|      1|           1| 'AAA'|    '70'|              |        |
|      2|      2|           2|   'C'| '39.95'|'only on this'|        |
+-------+-------+------------+------+--------+--------------+--------+
```

Comment: This is excellent, however I have listed only the part of the XPATH over here, the number of columns are dynamic, in my case . Is there a way to derive all columns dynamically without harcoding , may be values of the rows to be transformed as the column but without specifically typing it

Comment: Updated solution with dynamic columns list.